# VMWare unable to enumerate USB Devices

Tags: usb, virtualbox, vmware

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 23.10 running VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 7.0.10_Ubuntu r158379

When I boot the Virtual Box interface up, it immediately pops up the error:

```
Failed to enumerate host USB devices.
Could not load the Host USB Proxy service: VERR_DISK_FULL.
Result Code:
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0X00004005)
Component:
HostWrap
Interface:
IHost {e54f6256-97a7-4947-8a78-10c013ddf4b8}
```

The laptop is setup with a ZFS file system with over 1 TB free:

```
$ zfs list
NAME                  USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
UbuntuZFS            6.10T  1.02T   192K  none
UbuntuZFS/home       1.93T  1.02T  1.84T  /home
UbuntuZFS/replicant  4.10T  1.02T  4.10T  /mnt/replicant
UbuntuZFS/root       78.7G  1.02T  58.6G  /
```

I've tried removing and re-installing the VBox extension pack, but that did not change the error.

This error is popping up before any virtual machines are opened.

Syslog has the following info:

```
023-11-15T14:44:07.550689-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.888264] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/log.c:551:41
2023-11-15T14:44:07.582740-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921116] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:861:45
2023-11-15T14:44:07.582757-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921373] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:930:19
2023-11-15T14:44:07.582766-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921529] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:931:19
2023-11-15T14:44:07.587163-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921679] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:937:19
2023-11-15T14:44:07.587179-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921827] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:1213:9
2023-11-15T14:44:07.587187-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.921998] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:917:15
2023-11-15T14:44:07.587228-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.922224] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:918:15
2023-11-15T14:44:07.587240-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12360.922404] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:919:15
2023-11-15T14:44:29.942888-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12383.281184] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:943:19
2023-11-15T14:44:29.942918-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12383.281600] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:944:19
2023-11-15T14:44:29.946752-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12383.281976] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:945:19
2023-11-15T14:44:58.114804-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12411.453334] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:951:23
2023-11-15T14:44:58.114817-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12411.453681] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:952:23
2023-11-15T14:44:58.118746-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12411.453981] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:958:23
2023-11-15T14:44:58.118774-05:00 fafnir kernel: [12411.454281] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxnetflt/linux/VBoxNetFlt-linux.c:1222:13
2023-11-15T14:52:00.059611-05:00 fafnir dbus-daemon[2333]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.182' (uid=1000 pid=45623 comm="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox" label="unconfined")
2023-11-16T08:25:23.667358-05:00 fafnir kernel: [76038.004783] input: BM20X-5.0 as /devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:000E:3412.0008/input/input34
2023-11-16T08:25:23.739025-05:00 fafnir /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[4725]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/misc/uhid/0005:000E:3412.0008/input/input34/event4"
2023-11-16T12:32:34.048520-05:00 fafnir kernel: [90867.964254] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxdrv/common/log/log.c:1558:29
2023-11-16T12:37:05.988567-05:00 fafnir kernel: [91139.906740] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.c:648:59
2023-11-16T12:37:05.988587-05:00 fafnir kernel: [91139.906898] UBSAN: array-index-out-of-bounds in /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/7.0.10/build/vboxdrv/SUPDrvGip.c:647:59
2023-11-16T12:38:40.046438-05:00 fafnir dbus-daemon[2333]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.263' (uid=1000 pid=45623 comm="/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox" label="unconfined")
2023-11-16T12:53:44.923189-05:00 fafnir systemd[4532]: app-gnome-virtualbox-86937.scope: Failed to add control inotify watch descriptor for control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-virtualbox-86937.scope: No space left on device
2023-11-16T12:53:44.923464-05:00 fafnir systemd[4532]: app-gnome-virtualbox-86937.scope: Failed to add memory inotify watch descriptor for control group /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-virtualbox-86937.scope: No space left on device
2023-11-16T12:53:44.944988-05:00 fafnir systemd[4532]: Started app-gnome-virtualbox-86937.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
2023-11-16T12:53:45.002296-05:00 fafnir virtualbox.desktop[86937]: Qt CRITICAL: inotify_add_watch(/home/alan/.config/ibus/bus/4ac0e7f5903b1e1023748f9563b86a21-unix-1) failed: (No space left on device)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further web research indicated that the error messages in syslog were complaining about being out of inotify watches, not disk space.

I had already had edited /etc/syctl.conf to allow 100,000 watches, but apparently this was not enough.

I increased the watch count to

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=2097152
```

rebooted, and viola, USB was happy and working.